# AssertionError Null selenium Test

Tags: java, testing, selenium

Hello I am with the following test with selenium, but I'm having to run it an error:

```
public class TestExemplo extends SeleneseTestNgHelper {
    @Test public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("http://gmail.com");
        selenium.type("Email", "edipofederle");
        selenium.type("Passwd", "pass");
        selenium.click("signIn");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("You are currently"));
    }
}

java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase.fail(SeleneseTestBase.java:372)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase.assertTrue(SeleneseTestBase.java:377)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase.assertTrue(SeleneseTestBase.java:381)
    at com.example.tests.TestExemplo.testUntitled(TestExemplo.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Could someone help me with this? Thanks..

Comment: What's the problem ? It looks like the assertion is just failing because the text does not exist at that page ?

Comment: Yes, this is look like, but the text exist... after i be logged in Gmail..

Comment: apparently the problem occurs after I already be logged in to gmail, because on the front page asserts happen successfully ...

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the text you are checking for is being loaded by JavaScript after the page has loaded.  This would mean that at the time the `assertTrue()` is called the text is not yet present.  You could either try a `waitForCondition()` or just a plain `Thread.sleep()` so that the text has a chance to populate before the `assertTrue()` runs.

Comment: Hi, I try do this, but dont work too, i am try do this with Watir too, but have the same probleam, after login i have error to the a text via xpath for example ... usgin a Thread sleep too....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Selenium driver thinks that the text does not exist and hence is returning false. Your assertion is failing because of that.

Can you check what the getHtmlSource method's output looks like? May be paste it here so that the presence of that text (or absence) can be

Pavan

Comment: in log eclipse     Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Comment: Hi, i note that any app then i need login asserts dont work fine, for exemple, for gmail initial page(before login) asserts work very well, but after login no. This for any application... i dont have idea why this happen... thanks